# Decoupling from the DOM and bringing functionality into a directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-directive

I am trying to make a Snap-to-Component Directive.  At this point I have made a proof of concept with logic that lives in the app component (which would possibly be replaced with Renderer2 HostListeners and HostBindings) and it looks like I would have to get the dom properties (child1L, child1R...etc.) of the children probably using Renderer2.  My question is how would you decouple what I have done so far into a directive or a group of parent and child directives?  Or at least what direction would you go from here?  I am new to using Renderer2, HostListeners, and HostBinding so I was wondering how a more experienced person would do this. Thank you. Here is my [current stackblitz.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-horizontalscrollsetup-logging2-working)

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component,ElementRef,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {

switchDirection = "first";
head: ElementRef;

@ViewChild('child01') child01;
@ViewChild('child02') child02;
@ViewChild('child03') child03;

  onScroll(event: Event) {
    let viewBoundaryL = (event.target as HTMLElement).scrollLeft;
    console.log("viewBoundaryL:" + viewBoundaryL);

//SNAP FROM FIRST TO SECOND CHILD
    if(viewBoundaryL >= 50 && this.switchDirection === "first"){
this.child02.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: "center"  });
setTimeout(() => {
     this.switchDirection = "second";
      //  console.log(this.switchDirection)
    }, 300);
    }

//SNAP FROM SECOND TO FIRST CHILD
    if(viewBoundaryL <= 310 && this.switchDirection === "second"){
this.child01.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: "center"  });
setTimeout(() => {
  this.switchDirection = "first";
  // console.log(this.switchDirection)
    }, 300);
    }

//SNAP FROM SECOND TO THIRD CHILD
        if(viewBoundaryL >= 370 && this.switchDirection === "second"){
this.child03.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: "center"  });
setTimeout(() => {
  this.switchDirection = "third";
  // console.log(this.switchDirection)
    }, 300);
  }

//SNAP FROM THIRD TO SECOND CHILD
        if(viewBoundaryL <= 615 && this.switchDirection === "third"){
this.child02.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: "center"  });
setTimeout(() => {
  this.switchDirection = "second";
  // console.log(this.switchDirection)
    }, 300);
        }     
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
 <div class="container"  (scroll)="onScroll($event)" >

<child1 #child01></child1>
<child2 #child02></child2>
<child3 #child03></child3>

</div>
```

Thanks for your insights!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to create an [attribute directive](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives).

You can easily create a [directive](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/generate-directive) by using the Angular CLI with the following command (you can provide a path as the name **core/directives/my-directive-name**):

```
ng generate directive <name-of-directive>
```

Then in the constructor you can add the following to get reference to the element.

```
el: ElementRef
```

Finally using a [HostListener](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener), or any technique to bind to the scroll event. You can place a call to your snap to element code (will have to change to just check for itself), the element then will check if itself needs to initiate the scroll. And if it meets the condition, then it does.

For further bonus points, you can add inputs for setting and when to snap to the element for example, you template with the directive will look like this:

```
<div [myDirective] [scrollAt]="300"></div>
```

And then in the directive itself you would have:

```
@Input() scrollAt: number = 300 // sets a default incase it isn't provided;
```

Then you can use this variable for your view boundary.

Hope this helps, or at least puts you on the right track!

Comment: Yes, excellen guidance thank you!  So if the directive is on the children of the element with the scroll events I could just do the hostlistener like you have stated but how would I dynamically reference the children's siblings? using renderer2 nextsibling (cant find tutorials)? envisioning something like this but wondering how I grab its siblings... <child2 windowsnap [scrollto]="50" [scrollfrom]="100">

Comment: The directive would be on each child, so then it would completely handle itself. And the Hostlistener would be inside the directive itself. Unless there is something I am missing into why you would like to grab the reference of its siblings?

Comment: // hostlistener scrollPosition

// onscroll. if scrollposition is outside this.child.boundary scroll to next sibling

Comment: you need the reference to use scrollIntoView(el.reference) right?

Comment: Yes, but the directive being on each element will have reference to itself, you can put the hostlistener for the document within the directive. It is fine to to have it in multiple areas, you can also have the hostlistener in the parent of the children, and then have it, update a variable and then pass the variable to the directive using @Input(), if you update the stackblitz to have the directive I'll be happy to update it and show you what I mean :)

Comment: Well thank you for the offer :)   To be clear i meant the reference to the sibling (not itself) so       'you need the reference to use scrollIntoView(el.referenceToSIBLING) right?'         Also, I have the directive there but I haven't used it bc its not hooked up quite right yet its called windowsnap.directive.ts

Comment: I made it into a directive! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51294027/angular-6-how-do-i-making-this-directive-dynamic-and-decouple-it-from-the-dom

Comment: it has completely different rules bc requirements changed, but I still need it to be decoupled from the DOM.  Thanks for the guidance sir

Comment: now its at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51312864/angular-6-snap-to-component-directive-is-not-working-in-chrome